# similar DOS Navigator's editor

Tags: text-editors

Does anyone remember DOS Navigator? It has a text editor that allows to copy/paste blocks of text. Does anyone know a Windows text editor with the same capability?

Comment: doesn't any smart editor in Windows have this abilty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean selecting and manipulating rectangular blocks of text instead of lines, then a few spring to mind:

- [Far](http://farmanager.com)'s editor can do that; just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/about.php) can do it as well; just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but the implementation is horrible. For example, your block can't extend further to the right than the length of the current line (even though other lines in the block may be longer). In my eyes, this is a bug.
- Visual Studio also allows this, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> again.
- VS Code uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to extend a selection down- or upwards, and normal <kbd>Shift</kbd> within the same line.

Comment: in Notepad++ you can just do alt+mouse select like in MS Word

Answer (score 2):

I have fantastic news for you.

MS Word, has always let you do a block highlight.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

How about [gvim](http://www.vim.org/)? You can easily copy and paste blocks using `yy` (yank) and `p` to paste.

For example, if you wanted to copy 3 lines starting on the line of the cursor, you'd first press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to ensure you were in command mode, then `3yy`.